# take performance as the only criterion for a smal site, which framework should I choose on a shared hosting?

Tags: grails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up a small full functional website for a small community on a shared hosting.  Scientific computing is quite heavy.  Scalability is not important.  The only criterion is performance.  Which framework would you suggest among the following:(or more) from your list)

1)Ruby on Rails
2) Grails
3) asp.net
4) zend

I'm really new to this area, only starting reading some books and googling different blogs...so your expertise is really appreciated!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will all depend on what stats package you chose to use. I doubt most shared hosts will want you running processor intensive statistical modeling jobs from a web application but you may be able to get away with it if you have light traffic. Take a look at [this list of stats packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statistical_packages) What ever you chose to use will determine your language/framework choice. Note since Grails is based off Java any of the Java packages should work with it. If you want to run a stats package separate from a web application then you probably need to look at getting a virtual private server or dedicated server. Giving users access to a stats package on a server if it's not through a web interface requires more setup and control then you will be able to do through shared hosting accounts.

Comment: There are several options for hosting Grails; I'm running a Grails app on a $10/month account at http://www.enjoyvps.com/

Comment: Thank you, Jared!  To give a more details: I want to install a statistical package to do statistical modeling, and to install some educational package for training purpose.  In terms of performance, I dont have exact requirement except that I want it to be as fast as possible.
thank you again!

Comment: Thank you, Burt for the site information.  How do you like their hosting serice (well supported?  decently fast?)?

Comment: That's not a shared host that's a VPS that requires you to fully manage the server. There are some shared hosts though, I found this list on the grails site.
http://www.grails.org/Hosting

Answer (score 0):

**asp.net mvc** is the most performant framework. (I did some similar research 6 months ago (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283935/what-technology-asp-php-joomla-rails-grails-for-a-website-from-scratch) I asked) and I came to this conclusion). I am not biased since I am a Grails fan :-)

However, I hope that you know that your web application performance depends mainly on your design (# of DB Queries...) rather than the technology or the programming language of your application.